# Python search section of lines in file

Tags: python

It is easy enough to search for a pattern in the lines of a file with:

```
z = "/path/to/file/log.log"

with open(z) as file:
    for line in file:
        x = "pattern"
        if x in line:
            print(line)
```

I am wondering if you can avoid searching the entire line and instead focus on just a section.  Even though this doesnt work something like:

```
for line[10:20] in file:
```

Essentially only searching that area and ignoring the rest as a way to speed up the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test if a pattern is contained in a specific slice of a line, instead of anywhere in the line, use:

```
for line in file:
    if pattern in line[10:20]:
        # found it
```

Comment: I tested this too and oddly it works fine locally but not on my log server.  Not sure if its just the server that sucks or because it has to call 'for line in file:" first

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
with open("file") as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp):
        if i >= 10 and i < 20:
             x = "pattern"
             if x in line:
                  print(line)
```